# Hierarchical checked tree control with tri-state checkboxes in wxPython?

Tags: python, treeview, wxpython, wxwidgets

As per the title, is this possible?

By tri-state, I mean the parent node is:

- Checked if *all* children are checked
- Unchecked if *all* children are unchecked
- Grey/Filled if *some* children are checked

I have used them previously in C# but cannot find an equivalent control/implementation for wxPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at [wx.lib.agw.CustomTreeCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl-module.html)?

I'm not sure it does tri-state out of the box, but it's written in Python, so it should be quite easy to extend it.

Comment: Sure, wx.lib.agw.HyperTreeList is an extension of CustomTreeCtrl that adds columns.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do the same thing with the `CustomTreeCtrl` and it does support tri-state check boxes.

When you create the root,

```
self.root= self.tree.AddRoot("root node",ct_type=1)
```

or a child node,

```
child= self.tree.AppendItem(parent,"child",ct_type=1)
```

it returns a `GenericTreeItem` object which you can change the attribute `_is3State` to True with,

```
self.root.Set3State(True)
```

or

```
child.Set3State(True)
```