# wxPython : having Checkbox as items of TreeCtrl

Tags: wxpython

I am reading a dictionary and display it's items on a wx.TreeCtrl structure and its nice.I tried to insert check box instead of a string as each item but it was not allowed .How can I add checkbox's as items of TreeCtrl ? I want to be able to select individual items or a complete subtree.This is a very usual scenario. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this in wxpython?

Comment: Am I right in assuming you want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552349/hierarchical-checked-tree-control-with-tri-state-checkboxes-in-wxpython It looks like a wx.CustomTreeCtrl is the way to go.